# How to save the A-B repeat part from a song in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have been able to capture a particular section from a song using the A-B feature of VLC. But now I want to save that particular section/clip from it.

Does VLC provide me a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an addon made to do that. It is working with the latest version of VLC on windows, but it doesn't seem like it is actively being maintained

https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154005